# Linking yaml-cpp 0.5.x library with g++ 7.1.0

Tags: gcc, stdstring, yaml-cpp, g++4.9, gcc7

I'm attempting to compile a relatively simple program using yaml-cpp 0.5.3 with g++ 7.1.0, and am getting a linker error. The minimal program code is:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main(int i_iArg_Count, char * i_lpszArg_Values[])
{
    std::string cszFilename = i_lpszArg_Values[1];

    YAML::Node                              cFile;
    cFile = YAML::LoadFile(cszFilename);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and links just fine under g++ 4.9.0, but under g++ 7.1.0 I get the error

```
/tmp/ccJruju7.o: In function `main':
tyaml.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `YAML::LoadFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

The compile command I am using for this case is `g++ tyaml.cpp -lyaml-cpp -o tyaml`. I can confirm that it is not a problem with the path to the library -- `LIBRARY_PATH` contains the correct path to libyaml-cpp.a and g++ 4.9.0 compiles it fine with the same path. The more complete code uses more of yaml-cpp, and it is only functions that require std::string that are causing the problem.

libyaml-cpp.a was compiled using g++ 7.1.0, so I don't think it is an issue with the library itself. I have confirmed that the library includes the `YAML::LoadFile` symbol, and takes type `std::string const &`

I am not able to continue using older versions of g++ on the system that I am using.

I have tried both yaml-cpp 0.5.1 and yaml-cpp 0.5.3, both suffer from the same problem. I suspect this is a problem with std::string implementation in some way.

Comment: It compiles with `gcc 7.2.0` and `yaml-cpp 0.5.3-3`.

Comment: yaml-cpp 0.5.3 was a clean install and built under gcc 7.1.0. 
It does seem related to the ABI issue; compiling with
`-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` succeeds. Is this an issue with the make setup for yaml-cpp?